# Differential equation of mass spring system with compliant stoppers

Tags: differential-equations, physics, code-request

I would like to solve numerically the differential equation for the displacement `x[t]` of a mass `m`-spring `k` system with compliant stoppers.

The equation should be something like:

```
m x"[t] == -k x[t] -F[t]
```

`F[t]` should be defined so that:

-it is `0` when `Abs[x]` is below a certain value `x0`

-it is equal to `- k2 (x[t] - x0)`  when `Abs[x]` is above `x0`.

Which *Mathematica* function should I use to define `F[t]` so that `NDSolve` can solve the corresponding equation?

Comment: Have you tried something? Can you post your (possibly failing) code?

Comment: Check out [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html) for `Condition`

Answer (score 2):

```
k = 1;
m = 1;
x0 = 1/2;
f1[k2_][t_, x_] := -k/m x;
f2[k2_][t_, x_] := -k/m x + k2/m (x0 - x);
f[k2_][t_, x_] := If[Abs@x <= x0, f1[k2][t, x], f2[k2][t, x]];
fb[k2_][t_?NumberQ, x_] := f[k2][t, x];
bsol = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] == fb[#][t, x[t]], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 10}] & /@ Range@5
ListLinePlot[bsol, Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> {{}, {-x0, x0}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It seems like on v9, the `WhenEvent` option could be used in this case to toggle the forcing function.

Comment: @TimothyWofford Yep, but WhenEvent has some subtleties  that I don't want to confront today :)

Answer (score 1):

Belisarius has a nice solution using `If` which I am more or less copying here for comparison. I've removed `t` from the forcing function because it doesn't actually depend on time explicitly. Note, both of us have assumed that you meant `F[t]==+k2(x-x0)` when `Abs@x > 0` because otherwise you get exponential growth.

```
k = 1; m = 1; x0 = 1/2;
F0[k2_][x_] := If[Abs@x > x0, k2 (x - x0), 0]
```

In the comments I suggested `Condition`

```
F1[k2_][x_] /; Abs@x <= x0 := 0
F1[k2_][x_] /; Abs@x > x0 := k2 (x - x0)
```

Another option is `Piecewise`

```
F2[k2_][x_] := Piecewise[{{k2 (x - x0), Abs@x > x0}}, 0]
```

And for those of us still running v8,

```
bsol = x[t] /. NDSolve[{
   m x''[t] == -k x[t] - F2[#][x[t]],
   x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 10}] & /@ Range@5;
Plot[bsol, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Harmonic oscillator with various compliant stoppers]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, the Piecewise function works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the code based on the function you have. Free vibration of SDOF systems (undamped) draws displacement velocity and acceleration with respect to time can be calculated as in below code. Some demos can be found at Wolfram demonstrations site. [demo1](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TunedMassDamper/) [demo2](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FreeVibrationsOfASpringMassDamperSystem/) [demo3](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SimulatingVehicleSuspensionWithASimplifiedQuarterCarModel/)

```
m = 2;
k = 8;
w = Sqrt[k/m];

u = DSolve[{y''[x] + (w^2)*y[x] == 0, y[0] == 3, y'[0] == 5}, y[x], x][[1, 1, 2]] // Simplify
```

> 3 Cos[2 x] + 5 Cos[x] Sin[x]

```
v = D[u, x]
```

> 5 Cos[x]^2 - 5 Sin[x]^2 - 6 Sin[2 x]

```
a = D[v, x]
```

> -12 Cos[2 x] - 20 Cos[x] Sin[x]

```
p1 = Plot[u, {x, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"time in secs", "displacement"},
    PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.01]}];
p2 = Plot[v, {x, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"time in secs", "velocity"}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.01]}];
p3 = Plot[a, {x, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"time in secs", "acceleration"},
    PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.01]}];
{p1, p2, p3}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess you missed the requirement with respect to the constraints on F?

Comment: Yes you are right. The Question was not so clear. So, I gave a sample code to start with toying.